# Are there examples of robots using diff_drive_controller in ros2_control?

Tags: ros, ros2, diff-drive-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are working on the development of a custom differential drive robot using ROS 2 Foxy. Until now, our development was in simulation only and we are now transferring our code to the actual physical robot. I was looking into ros2_control to describe our hardware components and I thought it would be logical to use the diff_drive_controller. So, I have been looking for examples using this approach. However, I have not found any repositories that use ros2_control with the diff_drive_controller. Is anyone aware of physical robots that uses ros2_control with the diff_drive_controller controller in ROS 2 Foxy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373220/are-there-examples-of-robots-using-diff_drive_controller-in-ros2_control?/) by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2021-03-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matous Pokorny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52629/matous-pokorny/) on 2021-04-22**:
Hello Wilco, we are in the same situation and looking for a ros2_control diff_drive_controller example.

**Comment by [Webadone](https://answers.ros.org/users/72129/webadone/) on 2021-05-06**:
Hey, I also started with ros2_control stuff. I'm atm trying to get it running but I encounter a wired bug. Just posted the question here https://answers.ros.org/question/377820/ros2_control-created-node-by-controllerinterface-gets-nodename-of-controller_manager-no-matter-what-diff_drive_controller/

Do you have it already running on your robot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

There is an example for a simple diff-drive robot in [ros2_control_demos repository](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos).

See [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos#diffbot) for the explanation how the example works.

Is this what you have searched for?

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2022-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on 2022-02-17**:
That was not available at the time of writing the question, but that is indeed what we were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are using diff_drive_controller with a physical (and simulated) robot here:
https://github.com/memristor/mep3/

Firmware:
https://github.com/memristor/mep3/tree/main/firmware/motion_board

ros2_control hardware interface implementation:
https://github.com/memristor/mep3/blob/main/mep3_driver/src/motion_board_driver.cpp

Launch file:
https://github.com/memristor/mep3/blob/main/mep3_driver/launch/driver_launch.py

---

Originally posted by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) with karma: 486 on 2022-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2